# Concepts about data distributions

Tags: machine-learning

I'm a little confused here
is there a connection between data distribution and detecting novelty, I mean can data distribution differ between novelty, noise, or outlier? In order to detect them!

Another point need to be answered as well:
"training data and test data are drawn from the same distribution or the same feature space "
so when exactly does the data distribution change? And when the data distribution changes, on which set I'm supposed to focus on? where/when can this happen?

Comment: your question is out of topic

Comment: Not a programming question, better suited for [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest reading [this](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/outlier_detection.html) from scikit-learn. I think it is a good overview from which you can understand the difference between outlier and novelty detection. Basically novelty is a cluster of "outliers" but which being so close to each other represent a new kind of data partition probably, not simply something strange. Definitely, for the first such point, there is no way to discriminate between the two possibilities, but if you process your new data in batches and you detect high-density regions in the outlier spaces, you might suspect some novelty in the data.

For your second point, this is basically what [concept drift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concept_drift) is about.

Comment: can we talk more about this in slack?